# How can i find element which is below to the another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to drag and sort images using jquery UI. I have cloned element which is I am trying to drag. I need to show a line between two images based on cloned image position. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Here is the one example.
http://jsbin.com/owuxek/9/edit?html,js,output

I am showing images instead of "Item A Item B.." Now I need to show a line between two li's while one 'li' is moving.

EDIT: That is, when I click "and pick" an image and hover it onto the list of images already in place, I wish to show a 'separator line' between the images over which I am currently hovering, so as to indicate to the user where the image would be placed if user releases the mouse click.

In the attached JSbin code, when I move an element from the list above and try to move it into the list below, a small white separating space appears between the elements of the list below, over which the mouse hovers. I need to replicate this effect for the below element layout.

```
<div id="single_album_grid" class="sortable">
  <div id="divId1">
    <img class="assetImg"  id="imageId1"  src="url">
  </div>

  <div id="divId2">
    <img class="assetImg"  id="imageId2"  src="url">
  </div>

  <div id="divId3">
    <img class="assetImg"  id="imageId3"  src="url">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my updated code:

```
$( "#divId1" ).draggable({ 
    containment: $('#single_album_grid'), 
    helper: 'clone' 
    });

    $( "#divId1" ).droppable({
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                }

            });
```

Comment: Please provide more specific details about the elements hierarchy you are working with.

Comment: We have no idea what your structure looks like and surely aren't going to guess. Provide enough html for people to be able to help you

Comment: added structure...please check

Comment: @SarathChandra added some elements

Comment: @charlietfl added few elements please check

Comment: Let me see if I understood what you need. Are you referring to the effect of showing a small strip of white space created between two elements, when the cloned element is hovered in between them? Is that what you want ?

Comment: @gambler "*I have cloned element which is I am trying to drag*" - where is the code you've so far for this..? which jquery ui widget are you using..? You should specify these things when asking a question, else it's hard for anyone to answer it, which is why you're getting down voted. Hope the answer helps, if not update the question with further info

Comment: as per your updated code, `#divId1` is a draggable, `#divId1` is a droppable as well... if you apply this to the rest of `div`s what is the expected result after a drop..? `#divId1`  entirely inside `#divId2`.? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Please share a [mcve] with all the css that demonstrates the alignment of these things, and the way drag and drop is expected to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
over: function (event, ui) { 
   //code here 
}
out: function (event, ui) { 
  //code here
}
```

worked for me!!

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery UI [sortable widget](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/), it automatically inserts a placeholder element to at the target position.

You can style it like a line or whatever else you want with `.ui-sortable-placeholder` selector via css.

---

```js
$(function() {
  $("#single_album_grid").sortable()
});
```

```css
div div {
  height: 50px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  visibility: visible !important;
  height: 5px;
  background: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="single_album_grid" class="sortable">
  <div id="divId1">
    <!--img class="assetImg" id="imageId1" src="url"-->
  </div>

  <div id="divId2">
    <!--img class="assetImg" id="imageId2" src="url"-->
  </div>

  <div id="divId3">
    <!--img class="assetImg" id="imageId3" src="url"-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! @T J 

Actually I need to show line when drag element is cloned...

$( "#divId1" ).draggable({
            containment: $('#single_album_grid'),
            helper: 'clone'
});

By using clone i need to show a line...